# Why "close" event when something goes wrong with node-amqp?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqp

(I am using node-amqp and rabbitmq server.)

I am trying to guess why I have a close event if something goes wrong. For example, If I try to open a a connection to a queue (with bad parameters) I receive an error event. That it is perfect ok.

But, after any error I will receive also a close connection (in that case, maybe because close the failed socket to the queue). And after that, auto-reconnect and I receive the (initial) ready event.

The problem:

```
connection.on('ready', function() {
 do_a_lot_of_things

}).on(error, function(error){
 solve_the_problem
});
```

if something goes wrong, I receive the error, but then "ready" event and it will re do_a_lot_of_things. Is my approach wrong?

best regards

Comment: I think the reason is that when you try to create a queue (wrong configuration) into rabbitmq this emmit and error and after that it closes the connection. 
After that, node-amqp make the reconnect (if configured in that way). If connection success ready event is raised again and do_a_lot_of_things is done again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `connection.once('ready', function () { … })` (see [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_event_listener)), which will execute the handler only on the first event.

Comment: This seems OK to solve my current problem. But, Why am I receiving this sequence of close/ready? If something really important happens, for example: the rabbit server goes down, then I would like to know when it is up again receiving the "ready" event. Thus, I could react to it.

Comment: (I'm not familiar with the node-ampq module). You can also add a second listener with `.on('ready')` to react on those events.